# What is Loading GAX Client mean? Is this an error?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I'm currently working with build environments and following a few tutorials to load a plist with environmental variables. However I ran into the following in my prompt of Xcode

`[Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************`

Nothing should be printing out of my View controllers yet this popped out

Tried to search the web but didn't find anything useful to understand why this was printed out.

Was wondering if somebody could shed some light on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This is just an information. You have "Guided Access" turned on on your iOS device. The accessibility features of iOS inject unexpected libraries into your process and the app will report this to Xcode.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want this error to appear in your logs you can turn it off. 
Follow these steps to turn off Guided Access:

1. Go to your iPhone settings.
2. Select General.
3. Select Accessibility.
4. Scroll Down & Select Guided Acces.
5. Turn off Guided Access.

This error should not appear in the logs anymore.